# Is "modulo" a verb? If so, how is it conjugated?

Tags: terminology, modulo

I'm trying to document my implementation of a circular coordinate system. I made up the word "moduloed" to express its inner workings.

```
/**
 * Sets the value at a point
 * @param theta can be any value, will be moduloed to range [0, Circumference)
 * @param radius in range [0, Radius)
 */
setPoint(double theta, double radius, int value) {
    theta = Math.floorMod(theta, Circumference);
    matrix[(int)theta][(int)radius] = value;
}
```

Most of the other mathematical operations have a past tense (*ex. divided*) and present tense (*ex. divides*). Can we use "moduloed" and "modulos"? Is there a way of phrasing this that avoids using modulo as a verb?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it’s about English grammar (or maybe math terminology) and has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: @matt: I don’t buy that documentation is not part of good programming, nor that correct technical terminology about common computer arithmetic is not part of good documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, "modulo" is not a verb.  It's [the Latin ablative of modulus which itself means "a small measure."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_(jargon))

It is technically [mathematical jargon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_jargon):

> commonly used phrases which are part of the culture of mathematics, rather than of the subject

I recommend you rewrite that documentation sentence as simply:

> Theta is the angle in radians from the X-axis.

If you feel like you need to conjugate "modulo", your sentence is probably already obtuse (haha).  But you could elaborate each on a case by case basis:

> Note:  Theta is converted to the smallest non-negative coterminal angle.

Answer (score 2):

The verb is to **reduce** a number **to** a range (or **modulo** another number).

Comment: I think that would make `modulo` a preposition.